# Error while loading data from CSV file to MySQL Database Table in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, csv

I've created the following table in a MySQl Databse

```
CREATE TABLE aux(
    person   VARCHAR(40)      NOT NULL,
    uid      VARCHAR(90)      NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cp_aux PRIMARY KEY (uid)
);
```

Following this operation, I attempted to load its data from a system file called **data_aux.csv**. The contents of said file are the following:

```
person,uid
joelgonzaleztkd,10611110110810311111012297108101122116107100
atletiantimadrid_,97116108101116105971101161051099710011410510095
alex.silvestresz,9710810112046115105108118101115116114101115122
susannahmakram,11511711597110110971041099710711497109
henry.r6,1041011101141214611454
```

The command that I'm using the Python to load the data is the same that I've used in other tables:

```
mycursor.execute('''LOAD DATA INFILE 'data_aux.csv' INTO TABLE aux 
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                    ENCLOSED BY '"' 
                    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
                    IGNORE 1 ROWS;''')
```

However, when I list the contents of the table `aux` I get the following:

```
mysql> SELECT * from aux;
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| person            | uid                                              |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| henry.r6          | 1041011101141214611454                           |
| lgonzaleztkd      | 10611110110810311111012297108101122116107100     |
| akram             | 11511711597110110971041099710711497109           |
| lex.silvestresz   | 9710810112046115105108118101115116114101115122   |
| atletiantimadrid_ | 97116108101116105971101161051099710011410510095  |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)  ---- #**Why is the data not displayed organizedly**?
```

As you can see, the database knows that there are 5 rows, but I know for a fact that, internally, the information is not being stored correcty. Why? Because when I try to reference the column `id` as a foreign key (for example, `1041011101141214611454`), it says that said ID does not exist. If I do `SELECT id from aux where person='henry.r6'`, the database has the ID but there's something wrong with the form of the table and I can't tell what it is. (The "|" in the command above are not placed correctly for some reason and I'm pretty much certain that that's being troublesome).

However, if I insert the rows one by one, instead of using a file, the database contents are consistent and I can successfully reference the `id`. More specifically, the table looks like this when I do the inserts "by hand" (I skipped 2 entries for simplicity, but please notice the form of the table):

```
mysql> SELECT * from aux;
+--------------+----------------------------------------------+
| person       | uid                                          |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------+
| henry.r6     | 1041011101141214611454                       |
| lgonzaleztkd | 10611110110810311111012297108101122116107100 |
| akram        | 11511711597110110971041099710711497109       |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would like to know why when I load the data from a file, is causing said mistakes. I've used the same command in my other tables (with different .csv files), with other foreign keys and I had no problem whatsoever. Is there something with the command, or maybe something with the file?

Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: *Why is the data not displayed organizedly* You have Windows-style text file, so `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` must be used. *Because when I try to reference the column "id" as a foreign key (for example, 1041011101141214611454), it says that said ID does not exist.* Due to incorrect line termination literal your column values contains excess trailing `'\r'` char.

Comment: @Akina Thank you very much! Have a great day.